# Issue with Decoding H.263 Sorenson Spark D frames

Tags: ffmpeg, frames, disposable

I am trying to decode the H.263 sorenson type of data using avcodec_decode_video function.

It is able to decode the I and P frames but i have some D frames (Disposable inter frames) in my data and this function is not able to decode these frames and I am getting zero as return value.

So, can somebody tells me how we can decode these type f frames as I am not finding any mention of D frame sin the ENUM value also.

I have read somewhere that we can convert D frames into P frames  but if we have raw data how we achieve that if we want to use the decode function directly.